# Finding the intersection between a set of points and a set of multipolygons

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

I am trying to use the urbnmapr package to assign county FIPS codes to latitude, longitude data. I have set both CRS to 2163, which seems to be the default setting in urbnmapr. However, the values of the urbnmapr geometries are very different from the values of my points and this doesn't work. All of my points end up with the same FIPS code.

```
library(urbnmapr)
counties_sf <- get_urbn_map(map = "counties", sf = TRUE)
head(counties_sf)
```

[image: head of urbnmapr dataset]

My points are more typical:

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(5, 7, 8), lat = c(-100.92, -78.09, -96.96), 
              lon = c(35.35, 37.71, 38.52))

df_sf <- df %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_transform(crs = 2163)

head(df_sf)
```

[image: head of demo dataframe]

If I set the CRS to any other value for the urbnmapr set, the geometry values do not change. What am I missing to get these points assigned to the correct county_fips value for the multipolygons?

Edit: Using `st_transform` answered the initial question and got the sets in the same CRS, I'm still not sure why they won't come together.

```
fips_place <- sf::st_join(df_sf, counties_sf)
```

Comment: the `crs = ` argument does not convert your coordinates, it only _sets_ them to the CRS you specify. If you want to convert them you need to use `sf <- st_transform(sf, crs = 2136)`. So in your example I _think_ you need to do `st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>% st_transform(crs = 2163)`

Comment: Thanks, but this did not seem to make any difference in the output.

Comment: can you update / edit your question showing what you tried?

Comment: I made a mistake when I tried it the first time. It does produce the desired transformation.  Now I see I have more work to do further down the line.